# Run Hierarchy Viewer on W7(doesn't work)

Tags: android

I am working on Android. I try inside a terminal execute
java -jar hierarchyviewer.java

And I have this error

11:46:48 E/adb: Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "adb": CreateP
rocess error=2, the system cannot find the file specified

I can run the hierarchyviewer.jar from /tools/lib (double click) I can see the graphic interface but it does not show anything, I cannot see the tree and stuff. I am using Windows 7, 64 bit and I am executing the emulator and/or the device before running hierarchyviewer.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to add path of android SDK to PATH environment variable.

Comment: thanks but i have never understood how to add a path. Can you explain me more?

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: I am still have the same problem i put de path like: /tools/lib/hierarchyviewer.jar I also put java -jar hierarchyviewer.jar and i have the same error with a difference that now the hierarchyviewer is open but without devices....no solution yet

Comment: I also tryed the same on linux (ubuntu) and i have exactly the same problem. Someone can use hierarchyviewer properly?